# Property 'userStatus' is used before its initialization. ts(2729)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm actually borrowing this code somewhere from youtube for my project and I have accidentally stumbled upon this error:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseService {

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private firestore: AngularFirestore , private router: Router) { }

  public currentUser: any;
  public userStatus: string;
  public userStatusChanges: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.userStatus);
  

  setUserStatus(userStatus: any): void {
    this.userStatus = userStatus;
    this.userStatusChanges.next(userStatus);
  }
```

The error that I'm currently getting at the moment:

Property 'userStatus' is used before its initialization.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize it, maybe at the time of declaration:

```
public userStatus: string = ''; // or: null, undefined, whatever suits your case
```

Or maybe in a constructor:

```
constructor() {
  this.userStatus = '';
}
```

Probably the youtube tutorial is not using strict null checks, and they don't have the issue you are having.